# C# DateTimeOffset formatting to a certain format

Tags: c#

Is there any reference where I could find out how I can create a format for the DateTimeOffset that would enable me to produce a string like this?

```
2016-10-01T06:00:00.000000+02:00
```

I have a DateTimeOffset that I can work with, but I'm not sure how I could format it to produce the above string representation?

Comment: Look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Roundtrip

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> The "O" or "o" standard format specifier corresponds to the `yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fffffffK` custom format string for DateTime values and to the `yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fffffffzzz` custom format string for DateTimeOffset values.

```
DateTime lDat = new DateTime(2009, 6, 15, 13, 45, 30, DateTimeKind.Local);

Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1}) --> {0:O}\n", lDat, lDat.Kind);
// 6/15/2009 1:45:30 PM (Local) --> 2009-06-15T13:45:30.0000000-07:00 

DateTimeOffset dto = new DateTimeOffset(lDat);
Console.WriteLine("{0} --> {0:O}", dto);
// 6/15/2009 1:45:30 PM -07:00 --> 2009-06-15T13:45:30.0000000-07:00
```

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Roundtrip

Answer (score 12):

What you want is an [ISO 8601-standardized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations) combined Date and Time string.

The ["o" format string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx) provides you with just that:

```
DateTimeOffset dto = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now);
string iso8601date = dto.ToString("o")
```

Comment: what about if we want to convert to other formats like 2008/1/1 or 2008/01/01

Comment: @sabertabatabaeeyazdi substitute your custom format string for `"o"`: `dto.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");`